# twitter bootstrap carousel row layout, no slide

Tags: javascript, html, twitter-bootstrap

Ive been trying to learn and use twitter bootstrap, especially the carousel element. To this end, I have managed to replicate the example in the documentation and everything seems fine - works as expected. My sample HTML carousel code is on: http://dpaste.com/772419/

However, what I would like to do is, tell bootstrap not to make a slide, but rather show all the three (how many ever are present) images in one row - similar to how amazon displays its products. I have read the documentation, but could not figure out how this can be done.

Any thoughts, guidance would be very much appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: Sorry if this is a dumb question, but I am a bit confused by your question. So you want multiple images to load in one slide? Is that correct?

Comment: @KrisHollenbeck, yes, that is correct. So, for example, something like what amazon.com does on their end of landing page.So, multiple images along with their respective caption to appear (and not slide).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From my experience using bootstrap in the past I have used this HTML structure. So I believe you could just load multiple images in one slide... Like below..

```
<div class="carousel">
      <div class="carousel-inner">

    <!-- your slide -->
         <div class="item active">
                <div class="product">
                    <img src="" alt="" />
                    <p>this is a caption</p>
                </div>
                <div class="product">
                    <img src="" alt="" />
                    <p>this is a caption</p>
                </div>
                <div class="product">
                    <img src="" alt="" />
                    <p>this is a caption</p>
                </div>

         </div> 
    <!-- end slide -->

    <!-- your slide -->
         <div class="item">
                <div class="product">
                    <img src="" alt="" />
                    <p>this is a caption</p>
                </div>
                <div class="product">
                    <img src="" alt="" />
                    <p>this is a caption</p>
                </div>
                <div class="product">
                    <img src="" alt="" />
                    <p>this is a caption</p>
                </div>
         </div> 
    <!-- end slide -->

      </div>

</div>
```

Basically each DIV with the tag ITEM on it is a slide. And ACTIVE determines the first slide.

**EDIT**

Okay so I messed around with it a bit locally trying to reproduce your problem. It looks like the caption issue is most likely coming from the CSS in the bootstrap.css file. Here is the code...

```
.carousel-caption {
position: absolute;
right: 0;
bottom: 0;
left: 0;
padding: 10px 15px 5px;
background: #333;
background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.75);
}
```

The problem here is that your captions are positioned to the bottom of the item container. So the reason you can only see one is because of position:absolute; Making them all lay on top of each other. So most likely for your case you will need to tweak this CSS to get what you are looking for.

**Also note:** If you don't want to change the twitter bootstrap CSS you could add a class to your body tag and use pseudo classes to overwrite the bootstrap CSS.

**How to make the images display in columns:**

To make the images columns you could do a structure similar to this...

**HTML**

```
<!-- product one -->
<div class="product-container">
    <img src="" alt="" />
    <div class="carousel-caption">
        <h4>Something For Sale</h4>
       <p>Some description</p>
    </div>
</div>


<!-- product two -->
<div class="product-container">
    <img src="" alt="" />
    <div class="carousel-caption">
        <h4>Something For Sale</h4>
       <p>Some description</p>
    </div>
</div>


<!-- product three -->
<div class="product-container">
    <img src="" alt="" />
    <div class="carousel-caption">
        <h4>Something For Sale</h4>
       <p>Some description</p>
    </div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.product-container {
   width:33%;
   float:left;
}

.product-container img {
  margin:0 auto 0 auto;
}
```

That should get you in the ball park anyways... It might need to be tweaked a bit.

Comment: I have tried this based on intuition. However, it does not work. When you do this, the second image appears on the bottom of the first image and also captions do not work (how do you specify 2 captions under the same div"item-active"?) Please see my code on: http://dpaste.com/772427/  I have used twitters example here.

Comment: Hmm... okay I am going to fiddle with it for a moment and get back to you. Also, how large are the images? Most likely the stacking is occurring because of a CSS issue, or your images are to big for your container. As for the captions though, I am going to see if that is an issue with the plugin.

Comment: Thanks Kris for your help. I plan to use reasonably small images (example: http://ecx.images-amazon.com/images/I/512jiu1zhzL._SL500_SL135_.jpg), but at the moment Iam simply using twitter examples to simulate the examples. Ideally, I'd like to load 5 such images, alongside their captions.

Comment: Okay ... once you tweak the CSS for the captions and the images. They should be able to all display and fit properly with in the Item container...

Comment: Kris, How do you get the images to lay out in "rows" rather than "column" tho? At the moment, the second images comes below the first images rather than alongside it.

Comment: Thanks a lot Kris, that really helps! I am now able to see the images as rows and not as columns. I havent tested the captions yet, will do this soon. Thanks again - I have accepted your answer.

Comment: That is good to hear. I am glad I could be of help. Good luck with the rest of your project.